# createForm with object retrieved in database

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I've a strange problem, an error is throwed when i try to create a form with an object retrieved in database:

```
$user = $this->getUser();

try {

  $group = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MuzichCoreBundle:Group')
    ->findOneBySlug($slug)
    ->getSingleResult()
  ;

} catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Groupe introuvable.');
}

if ($group->getOwner()->getId() != $user->getId())
{
  throw $this->createNotFoundException('Vous n\'ête pas le créateur de ce groupe.');
}

$form = $this->createForm(
  new GroupForm(), 
  $group,
  array('tags' => $this->getTagsArray())
);

return array(
  'group' => $group,
  'form'  => $form->createView()        
);
```

=>

> Expected argument of type "array", "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" given

But, if it's a new object, no problems:

```
$form = $this->createForm(
  new GroupForm(), 
  new Group(),
  array('tags' => $this->getTagsArray())
);
```

=> no error

Do you now what's the problem ?

**Edit**: Problem "solved", see comments bellow.

Comment: You're using an invalid type in `$group`.

Comment: how solve it ? It's an object retrieved in database, why is it uncompatible with form ?

Comment: I've found it, it's an collection of entity in attribute. It's normal what i can't use it directly in form ? (if i remember, no problem in symfony1.x)

Comment: Well your program is reporting that it can not deal with that type. I don't think that symfony2 is backwards compatible either. Check the form tutorial on the symfony2 website, it handles database persistence with doctrine: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need getSingleResult, only:

```php
$group = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MuzichCoreBundle:Group')
    ->findOneBySlug($slug)
;
```

Comment: In really, i've personalize this method for return Doctrine\ORM\Query